# Hyperref with Teubner

Tags: hyperref, greek

I need to have greek words in bibliographical entries and links; the rest of the document is in several languages.

I use `teubner.sty` and works quite well in the bibliography. I tried `textgreek.sty` but it can't help with the accents and it doesn't work with `hyperref.sty`. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\textgreek{AB\'agARE}

\url{abc\textgreek{AB\'agARE}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May be `\href{real url}{abc\textgreek{AB\'agARE}}` ?

Comment: the real url contains greek characters which are automatically converted to question marks. Therefore 

    \href{https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Τετερίτες}{https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/\textgreek{Tenter\'itec}} 

redirects here [https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/?????????] instead of [https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Τεντερίτες]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with `pdflatex` the solution is to URL decode the greek characters in the URL argument in `\href` and show an alternative LaTeX text as secon argument.

When I copy a URL from a browser, is already decoded when pasted elsewhere in my OS, so the conversion seem easy, but if this fail in your system, an online tool as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ can save your day.

Example linking [Τετερίτες](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A4%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%82) in Wikipedia:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\usepackage{teubner}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\href{https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A4%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%AF%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%82}%
{el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Τεντερίτες} 

\end{document}
```